# How to use the same DI code in asp.net and a windows service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap

I have a question about how to use the same DI code in an ASP.NET mvc app and a windows service as both interact with the same database using NHibernate. The windows service however performs background tasks.

Like everyone I have a new controller factory that knows how to instantiate controllers using StructureMap. Thus I can have the required repositories given to my controllers as parameters of their constructors. Since Structuremap controls the ISession life cycle using the HTTPContextScope then I can be sure that all repositories receive the same instance of the ISession for every web request.

However in a windows service and using Structuremap (the same DI code) I don't know a nice way to logically isolate different background tasks to own a unique ISession instance and share it with the repositories they use. I want to have multiple tasks executing simultaneously, therefore the ISession can not be a singleton object (as recommended for desktop apps using NHibernate).

I want to preserve and introduce the One Session Per Request pattern in my windows service trusting Structuremap to give us the same ISession instance per Task. Can anyone point me towards the right direction?

Thanks

---

### EDIT

This two part post by [Corey Coogan](http://blog.coreycoogan.com/about/) is very much along the lines I think this problem should be resolved. However I'm not familiar with WCF and tend to get confused by its parts in the article.

http://blog.coreycoogan.com/2010/05/26/structuremap-wcf-nhibernate-part-1/
http://blog.coreycoogan.com/2010/05/27/structuremap-wcf-nhibernate-part-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Windows Service I have a bootstrapper which is exactly the same as the one in ASP.NET MVC:

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        StructureMap.ObjectFactory.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.UseDefaultStructureMapConfigFile = false;
            cfg.IgnoreStructureMapConfig = true;
            cfg.AddRegistry<Web.Core.DI.NhibernateRegistry>();
            cfg.AddRegistry<Web.Core.DI.DomainRegistry>();
            cfg.AddRegistry<Web.Core.DI.ServicesRegistry>();
            cfg.AddRegistry<Web.Core.DI.QuartzRegistry>();
        });
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new StructureMapServiceLocator(ObjectFactory.Container));
    }
}
```

then I have defined a registry for each module:

```
public class NhibernateRegistry: Registry
{
    public NhibernateRegistry()
    {
        SchemaOperation schemaOperation = SchemaOperation.None; 

        For<ISessionFactory>()
            .Singleton()
            .Use(new BpReminders.Data.NH.NHibernateSessionFactory(connectionString, schemaOperation).SessionFactory);

        For<IUnitOfWork>()
            .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
            .Use<BpReminders.Data.NH.UnitOfWork>();

        For<ISession>()
            .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
            .Use(o => ((BpReminders.Data.NH.UnitOfWork)o.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>()).CurrentSession);
    }
}
```

I bootstrap everything as soon as the service starts:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Bootstrapper.Initialize();
}
```

At the end I adopted a Singleton pattern cause my Windows Service doesn't use any extra threads.
I know that StructureMap has got a keyword AlwaysUnique which might be useful for what you're trying to do:

```
For<ISession>()
    .AlwaysUnique()
```

the code comments say (about AlwaysUnique)

***/// Forces StructureMap to always use a unique instance to

/// stop the "BuildSession" caching***

You have to dig in this cause I've just done a couple of test. Not much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ThreadLocal Lifeycle.  I've never used it myself, but it sounds like what you are looking for:

> PerRequest - The default operation.  A
>   new instance will be created for each
>   request.   Singleton - A single
>   instance will be shared across all
>   requests
>
> **ThreadLocal - A single instance will be created for each requesting thread.
>   Caches the instances with
>   ThreadLocalStorage.**
>
> HttpContext - A single instance will
>   be created for each HttpContext. 
>   Caches the instances in the
>   HttpContext.Items collection.
>
> HttpSession - A single instance will
>   be created for each HttpSession. 
>   Caches the instances in the
>   HttpContext.Session collection.  Use
>   with caution.
>
> Hybrid - Uses HttpContext storage if
>   it exists, otherwise uses ThreadLocal
>   storage

Comment: I think you're right but I don't know where to begin. Can you give me an example?